# Generate core file with original process name

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, core-file

I have a binary which will create multiple threads. Now when one of those threads crashes, I want the name of the core file generated to contain the original process name instead of the thread name.

When I use the %e specifier, it gives the thread name only (I think it is because in Linux, all threads are considered as LWPs).

How do I get the original process which created the thread in the core file name?

I looked at the [man file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html), but it does not have any other specifier which I can use.

Comment: I get the thread name when I use %e. I want to get the executable name (the process which created the thread)

Comment: What thread name? Theads don't have names. Please provide an example.

Comment: `%E` adds the path with the name of the executable.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/34801353/564626

Comment: @jfritz42 Nope, I did not :(

Comment: See the other question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/34801353/564626) for a workaround that I came up with.