# missing corefiles when SEGV occurs in thread different from main thread

Tags: multithreading, segmentation-fault, coredump, core-file

I am currently debugging a segfault in one of our c++ applications and it gives me a hard time since no core files are generated when the segfault occurs.

After some reading and checking ulimits and so on I can reproduce the case of core files not being generated. It seems somehow to be related with threads. For that purpose I altered our software to artificially generate SEGV:

Now the following pattern emerges

- SEGV in main thread      -> core file is generated
- SEGV in non-main thread  -> **no** core file is generated

Then in order to not alter the program itself I also tried the same with sending signals.

- Sending "kill -s SIGSEGV < pid >"      -> core file is generated

Then I search und /proc/< pid >/task for a non main thread and took the id

- Sending "kill -s SIGSEGV < threadid >"  -> **no** core file is generated

Do you know of any thread specific properties that would explain such a behaviour?

I also tried the same code under different OS and this only occurs on our production environment (redhat6) and not under Ubuntu.
I am still trying to figure out if it might be related to Debug/Non-Debug builds.

Still the behavior seems so strange that it must be because of some subtlety.
I also wonder, if I wanted to create this behavior on purpose I would not even know what to change, in order to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Best regards
Matthias

Comment: This may help: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: I read the page and do not see how it helps. The only point where threads are mentioned is in the naming of the corefile (which in my case does not exist) - could you elaborate how this could help?

Comment: If reading documentation doesn't help, you may like to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Unfortunately I cannot post a minimal example yet, because I have failed to create such an example that shows this behaviour. Every simply program I wrote produced nice core files both when the main thread or a non-main thread segfaulted.
What I am asking is more information - what some differences are for main thread and non-main thread differences.

Comment: College of @matthias here. We see this behavior on Scientific Linux 6.4. Maybe it's a bug/setting in the specific kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what its worth - it had something to do with the corepattern which I found out with some trial and error

```
core_pattern  core                   -> corefile
core_pattern  /opt/tmp/core          -> corefile
core_pattern  /opt/tmp/core_%e.%p    -> no corefile
core_pattern  /opt/tmp/core_%e       -> no corefile
core_pattern  /opt/tmp/core_%h       -> corefile
core_pattern  /opt/tmp/core_%h_%p    -> corefile
core_pattern  /opt/tmp/core_%h_%p_%e -> no corefile
```

So the %e seems to be reason why sometimes no core is written.
Then [core dump filename gets thread name instead of executable name with core_pattern %e.%p.core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801353/core-dump-filename-gets-thread-name-instead-of-executable-name-with-core-pattern)
explains what is going on - namely that %e is not the executable name but contains information about the threads - which in my case contains "/"

This also explains why segv in different threads behave differently and also why my simplest programs did not show the problem - as there was no code give names to the threads